# How to keep JNIEnv from going out of scope in thread?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

When I try to call JVM from thread in C++, debbuger says that JNIEnv pointer is gone. Code:

```
void thread_call(JNIEnv* env,jobject text_view,jmethodID setText,const char* str){
    env->CallVoidMethod(text_view,setText,env->NewStringUTF(str));
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_project_1lenspath_MainActivity_initPullThread(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject, jobject text_view){
     ...
     std::thread pull(thread_call,env,text_view,setText,std::to_string(t).c_str());
     ...
}
//Debugger:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'env'
```

Are there any ways to call JVM without JNIEnv or any other solution?

Comment: That `pull` thread should not receive a `JNIEnv*` as an argument. Instead, it should use `AttachCurrentThread` and `DetachCurrentThread` to get and dispose of its own `JNIEnv*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the jvm pointer inside `JNI_OnLoad`, e.g.

```c
JavaVM* g_jvm;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    g_jvm = vm;

    ...
    return result;
}
```

Then use this `g_jvm` to do `AttachCurrentThread` and `DetachCurrentThread`, e.g.

```c
void foo() 
{
    jint res = javaVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (res != JNI_OK) {
        res = javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        if (JNI_OK != res) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    ...

    g_jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

See: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp

Comment: `foo` should keep track of whether `AttachCurrentThread` was called, and only call `DetachCurrentThread` if that was the case.

Comment: That looks sort of like solution, but it still requires env pointer, which goes out of scope.

Comment: `env` can also be cached globally if you want.